# How do I set up an intranet that can be accessed in different locations?

Tags: server, wampserver, intranet

I want to set up an intranet that can be accessed in more than one location.
I want the server to be located in one location and be accessed in another. For example it would be at the users home, or in one of our many offices. At the moment I can't see more than 7 people using it, so we won't need anything large to start off with.

I use Wampserver for building our webpages, but I don't think Wampserver will be enough to do what we need. As if I set up Wampserver it is only accessible from the building we are in. I do not want to open the firewall to put it online as the pages that we will be serving will not be for the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of doing this is to set up and configure a VPN solution for your home users. You could do this yourself or use a third party solution. Normally, you would allow VPN users access to specific resources, such as your intranet server.

The other alternative is to allow public access to the intranet server, but implement authentication on the intranet server so only your users can access the content.

I would normally go for the former as a more secure solution,  but it depends on your environment and requirements.